# Python freezes on smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

Tags: python, smtplib

I am attempting to create a script that send an email, using Gmail. However, my code freezes when the line below is ran:

```
smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
```

It is before my username and password are entered, so it is nothing to do with my Gmail account. Why is this happening? I am using Python 3.6.3

The full code is below:

```
import smtplib

# Specifying the from and to addresses

fromaddr = 'XXX@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'YYY@gmail.com'

# Writing the message (this message will appear in the email)

msg = 'Enter you message here'

# Gmail Login

username = 'XXX@gmail.com'
password = 'PPP'

# Sending the mail  

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by freezes? Can you post any errors you are getting?

Comment: No errors, it just runs continuously..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is most likely a firewall or similar issue. On the machine having the issue, try running this on the command line:

```
ping smtp.gmail.com
```

Assuming that works, then try:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

I'm assuming a Linux machine with this command. You'll need to adapt for others. If that connects, type `ehlo list` and the command should show some info. Type `quit` to exit.

If that doesn't work, then check your iptables.

```
sudo iptables -L
```

This will either show something like `ACCEPT all` under `Chain INPUT` or if not, you'll need to ensure that you are accepting established connections with something like:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

The output chain is often open, but you should check that too.

If you are on AWS, check your security group isn't blocking outgoing connections.

Comment: I get info after telnet and `ehlo list` but in any case get the freeze on `smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.google.com',587)`

Answer (score 9):

If it's hanging in the call to smtplib.SMTP, and the server requires SSL, then most likely the issue is that you need to call smtplib.SMTP_SSL() (*note the _SSL*) instead of calling smtplib.SMTP() with a subsequent call to server.starttls() after the ehlo. See SMTPLib docs for SMTP_SSL for more details.

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This still freezes for me , both with and without the 587 parameter

Answer (score 3):

Use `server.ehlo()` in your code.

Code Snippet:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
```

For authentication error:
http://joequery.me/guides/python-smtp-authenticationerror/

Add following code snippet and run again.

```
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server.close()
    print 'successfully sent the mail'
except:
    print "failed to send mail"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, have added this in but it still freezes

Comment: No error is returned, the script just keeps running, I ran the script about an hour ago and it is still going.

Comment: That line is added after the line is added, how is that supposed to help?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `ehlo` call. These days, you do need an [app password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73136764/python-cannot-send-email-from-gmail-account-with-smtp) with Gmail. And crucially, you need the right server address. I stupidly copied `smtp.google.com` from some bad instructions, and the call hung. Changing to `smtp.gmail.com` fixed it. Duh.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to do before running your program:

1. Enable “App password”
   a.  Goto to myaccounts.google.com
   b.  Select “Security”
   c.  Enable 2 step verification(if not done earlier)
   d.  Click on 2 step verification again
   e.  Goto “App password” (At the bottom of page)
   f.  Select app : Other and Generate  - accordingly use app password
2. Enable IMAP
   a.  Click on setting(gear icon)
   b.  Click on “Forwarding and POP/IMAP”
   c.  Enable “Enable IMAP” (Select the radio button)

In you code for for connection use “smtplib.SMTP_SSL(”smtp.gmail.com”). and remove starttls()(incase if you are using)

Code for your ref:

```
import smtplib

my_email = xyz@gmail.com
to_addr=abc@yahoo.com
password = "Copy App password here"

connection = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com")
connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs="to_addr", 
msg="Subject:Hello\n\nHope this solves your issue”)
connection.close()
```

Hope this helps

Thanks
Abhi