# Python cannot send email from gmail account with smtp

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, gmail

I used gmail account to send email notification when my script fails. Since May 30, 2022, Gmail stops supporting access over **[Less secure app access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4OSomG36X3vbq9EKqy7mWvQ9fcJ4p4wZOWegykb7HPEIXQdhMhI1Pl93qynfwyy_ZcTBHIHo8JreW3TgmrM7jZ_-uBGKQ)**

```
This setting is no longer available.
```

From [Google support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en&visit_id=637945155448155425-2409975950&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1):

```
To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.
```

I am receiving python error even my user and password is OK (tested by logging to my account):

```
Authentication error. Wrong user or password.
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u2-20020a1709061da200b0072f42ca2934sm7507815ejh.148 - gsmtp')
```

What is the best way how to use google account for notification emails or is there better way or tool how to be notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to send email over Gmail SMTP, google enable you to set up App password. You have to have set up 2-Step verification in your google account. Once 16 digit password are generated, you just replace password for login (username is your email address, that does not change).

**Sources:**

- [Google: Sign in with App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)
- [Stackoverflow: What's solution for sending emails from python while gmail " the less secure apps " is not enabled anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72576260/whats-solution-for-sending-emails-from-python-while-gmail-the-less-secure-app)